# Does anyone know how I can make my code run faster?

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate Sigma(n=0 to infinity) (−1)^n/(n + 1) as accurately as possible. But my code takes forever and I am not able to see whether my answer is right. Does anyone know how I can make my code faster? The sum is supposed to converge to log(2). My idea is that f(n) will eventually become a very small number (less than 2^-52) and a time would come when R would consider sum = sum + f(n) and that's when I'd want the code to stop running. But clearly, that doesn't seem to work and my code takes forever to run and at least to me, it doesn't seem to ever stop.

```
f <- function(n) 
  return(((-1)^(n))/(n+1))


s <- function(f){
  sum <- 0
  n <- 0
  while(sum != sum + f(n)) {
    sum <- sum + f(n)
    n <- n + 1
  }
  return(c(sum, n))
}

s(f)
```

Comment: You could certainly improve performance by only executing `f(n)` once per loop, instead of twice. Put it in a local variable. Note also that your `while` condition is effectively saying "while `f(n)` is not zero" - is that what you want? Would it be better to compare against some very small epsilon?

Comment: I don't think that my while condition is effectively saying "while f(n) is not zero". From what I understand, it is saying "while f(n) is >= 2^(-52)".

Comment: the order of time needed for a small operation is about 10 nanosecond, that is 10-8s. If I'm correct for going until something smaller than 2.220446e-16 (the smallest double) you would need something like 10^8s that is 3 years. That is not a right algorithm choice ^^

Comment: @ArnaudFeldmann By the way, why is it that I get TRUE for 1e10 == 1e10 + 2^(-20) but FALSE for 1e10 == 1e10 + 2^(-19)? Shouldn't I be only getting TRUEs from 1e10 == 1e10 + 2^(-53) onwards?

Comment: @Quant007 As most of the languages uses the standard double-precision format. That roughly means, it has a bit of sign, 11 of exponent, and 52 of signifiant digits. 10 ^10 is already somewhat like 2^33 you only have 20 signifiant digits after the comma

Comment: Btw, r as an interpreted language got a strong overhead, contrary to the belief it can be quite fast in its field but will be disappointing for this kind of use that is better written in a compiled language.

Comment: (1) `sum != sum + f(n)` is the same as `f(n) != 0`, without the `sum`; this is far different from `f(n) >= 2e-52`, which happens when `f(1)` which equals `-0.5`; if you want `f(n) >= 2^-52`, then write it like that, otherwise your code is not doing what you *want* and it is an effectively-infinite loop. Perhaps you mean `abs(f(n) >= 2e-52)`? (2) Agree, multiple calls to `fn(n)` are unnecessary; perhaps `while (abs(fn <- fn(n)) > 2e-52) sum <- sum + fn`.

Comment: @r2evans that i disagree. sum != sum + f(n) isn't the same than f(n) != 0 cause sum has different signifiant digits. hence f(n) equals zero when it's smaller than 2^-1074, while adding something to something close to 1 will actually have somewhat a 2^-52 precision, cause the exponent bits in the double representation of something close to 1 can't change. Both small precision are way out of range anyway, and R isn't made for such low level considerations

Comment: So @Quant007 is right to think that a > 2^-52 is implicit when testing the equality, but then firstly it's a low-level consideration that has nothing to do in high level code, and then the 2^-52 is out of reach anyway on our computers

Comment: I see your point about loss of precision and concur with your assertion that it will make a difference with high levels of precision. If you know this already, then, why are you testing for strict `!=`? In any language, when working high levels of precision, you need to use strict inequality `>` or `<`. It is highly unlikely that you will ever see exactly `0`, and since your `f` is not monotonic (`f(0)` is pos, `f(1)` is neg, `f(2)` is pos again, etc), `sum` will continue to waffle up and down. I still think you should be testing for tolerance such as `abs(.) < 2e-52`.

Comment: @r2evans I don't do anything I just answer, I agree with you overall and just wanted to tell that the author Quant007 was right to think that the precision of its tested equality was somewhat 2^-52. But then, I agree, if he already knew that then there's no wonder why this is a verrrrrry long loop, out of reach with our computers.

Answer (score 3):

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction("
List s(int max_iter) {
  double sum = 0;
  double sum_prec=NA_REAL;
  double n = 0;
  for (;sum != sum_prec && n < max_iter;n++) {
    sum_prec = sum;
    sum+=pow(-1,n)/(n+1);
  }
  return  List::create( 
   _[\"sum\"]  = sum, 
   _[\"iterations\"]  = n, 
   _[\"precision\"] = sum-sum_prec
 ) ;
}")
test <- s(100000000)
test
```

When you use a huge number of subsequent iterations you know that R is not appropriated. However C++ functions are very easy to use within R. You can do something like that by example. The function needs a max of iterations and returns a list with your sum, the number of iterations and the precision.

EDIT : By precision I only do sum-sum_prec so this is not the real interval.

EDIT 2 : I let the sum != sum_prec for the example but if you don't have a supercomputer you're not supposed to see the end lol

EDIT 3 :

Typically, a fast R base solution would be something like :

```
base_sol <- function(n_iter) {
  v <- seq_len(n_iter)
  v <- (-1L)^(v-1L)/v
  list(
    sum = sum(v),
    iterations = n_iter,
    precision = v[length(v)]
  )
}
```

Which is only 1.5 times slower than c++, which is pretty fast for an interpreted language, but has the con of loading every member of the sum in ram (but then, R is made for stats not for calculating things at 2^-52)